# Postgres: Sort Unique Index by a separate column

Tags: postgresql, unique-index, composite-index

Consider a many-to-many relationship of books in a bookshelf:

```
CREATE TABLE bookshelf_books(
  bookshelf_id text NOT NULL,
  book_id text NOT NULL,
  ordering text NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bookshelf_book ON bookshelf_books(bookshelf_id, book_id);
```

When the index gets created, I assume it will order items by `bookshelf_id, book_id`.

**But what if I write a query that sorts by `ordering`?**

```
SELECT * FROM bookshelf_books WHERE bookshelf_id = 'foo' AND book_id = 'bar' ORDER by ordering LIMIT 10;
```

PG will have to run one more sort. **Is there a way to avoid the sort on ordering?**

I could get around it by creating one more index with ordering:

```
CREATE INDEX bookshelf_book_order ON bookshelf_books(bookshelf_id, book_id, order);
```

But this feels wasteful. Is it possible me to tell PG that while constructing the unique index, it should sort items with `ordering`?

Comment: What about removing the ```ORDER BY ordering``` from your query? After all, the unique constraint enforces that there is at most one row that passes through your ```WHERE``` clause. I cannot see a reason or effect to sort this one row.

Comment: Very basic SQL rule. If you do not use `order by` in the 'final query' then the sequence of rows is indeterminable. The **only** way to get a consistent order in the result set is `order by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the index over `bookshelf_id` and `book_id` is unique - your example query will return either zero or one row. Sorting requires at least 2 rows.
So, if you want to get all books for a given bookshelf or all bookshelfs where the given book is located - you will need 2 additional indexes:

- one non-unique index over `(book_id, bookshelf_ordering)` which will define how the bookshelfs for the given book will be ordered
- and another non-unique index over `(bookshelf_id, books_ordering)` which will define how the books in the given bookshelf will be ordered

Then you can query like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM bookshelf_books 
WHERE bookshelf_id = 'foo' 
ORDER by books_ordering 
LIMIT 10
```